# Download txt file with laravel and axios

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, download, axios, jquery-file-upload

**Hello there** 
Hope you will be doing good.I want to download txt file generated on the fly from the controller of laravel i have search alot but could not find any solution.Please help out i will be very thankful.

**Blade code with axios request**

```
submitHandler:function(form,e){
            var btn=document.querySelector("#BtnSubmit");
            btn.style.display="none";var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src",base_url+'front/images/loading.gif');
            var loader=document.querySelector("#loader");loader.appendChild(img);
            var url="<?php echo route('database.export-txtProcess');?>";
            var cur_url="<?php echo route('database.export-txt');?>";

            //var tblExportSelect  = $("#tblExportSelect").val();


            var pushArray = [];
            $.each($("#tblExportSelect option:selected"), function(){
            pushArray.push($(this).data("id"));
            });

            var data  = new FormData();

            data.append('tblExportSelect',pushArray);


            //$("#tblExportSelect").val(selected);


            axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
              })
            .then(function(res){
              console.log(res);
            })
         e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
```

**Controller Method**

```
public function exportTxtProcess(Request $request){

      /*dd($request->tblExportSelect);*/

       $tables  = explode(",", $request->tblExportSelect);

        $destinationPath = public_path('/');

        $result;

       foreach ($tables as $table) {
          $outputs   =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM $table");

          $today   = date("Y-m-d");
          $fileName  = $table."-".$today;
          $fp = fopen($destinationPath . "$fileName.txt","wb");

          foreach ($outputs  as $output) {
            $output  = (array)$output;

            @array_shift($output);

            $removeUserId  = @$output['user_id'];
            $created_at    = @$output['created_at'];
            $updated_at    = @$output['updated_at'];



            if (($key = array_search($removeUserId, $output)) !== false) {
                unset($output[$key]);
            }
            if (($key1 = array_search($created_at, $output))) {

                unset($output[$key1]);
            }

            if (($key2 = array_search($updated_at, $output))) {

                unset($output[$key2]);
            }

            if (is_null($created_at) OR $created_at == '') {
                unset($output['created_at']);
            }

            if (is_null($updated_at) OR $updated_at == '') {
                unset($output['updated_at']);
            }


            $netResult = $this->getTableFields($table,$output);

            fwrite($fp,$netResult);

          }

          $result = fclose($fp); 
       }
       /*$arr = array(['Good' => true,'message' => 'Data has been successfully imported.'], 200);
                    echo json_encode($arr);*/
       if ($result) {
        $pathToFile  = $destinationPath . "$fileName.txt";

        $downloaded = response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend();


       }
    }
```

I want to download when txt file which is created as above but instead of download it streaming in the console.

**Thank in advance**

Comment: Is it autheticated api endpoint or public?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the headers. Most importantly you are not returning the reponse.

```
   $headers = [
      'Content-type' => 'text/plain', 
      'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $fileName),
      'Content-Length' => sizeof($content)
    ];
        return response()->download($pathToFile, $fileName,$headers)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

Comment: @SadamHussain what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Bro please give me idea i have tried the edited code but could not working it is showing in the browser instead of downloading. @Adnan Mumtaz

Comment: I am not getting error.i am viewing the txt contents in the console instead of downloading.@AdnanMumtaz

Comment: There is no error but file contents are displayed in the response instead of downloading.i want to download the file.@Adnan Mumtaz

Comment: @SadamHussain there could be an alternative to this.. you can open it in a new tab using get request and then download the file.

Comment: @SadamHussain you can also try `return response()->file($filepath)`

Comment: I am getting file contents in the response.

Comment: getting this error :  sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countabl

Comment: `'Content-Length' => sizeof($content)` remove the above line

Comment: i have removed but file is not downloading.